# Aren't public wi-fi hotspots still insecure for Tails and Tor users?

Tags: security, ip-address, connection

If connecting to public wi-fi with only Windows and Chrome already makes a user cautious of their activity, how much more of a shield is it to connect to the same public wi-fi with a Tails-Tor system? We would still see the "connection is insecure" warning pop up wouldn't we? So what really is the benefit of making this change in system in terms of the scenario still being the same access poin? given that eavesdroppers would still be there, and the hotspot owner would see the Tor user and device name logged into their network

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? The wi-fi operator from seeing what sites you visit? And what "connection is insecure" warning are you referring to?

Comment: not so much traffic (because Tails and Tor handles that by nature), but to protect anonymity of identity, both of the user and the device being used by the user to connect to the network